# How to call a static method from a private base class?

Tags: c++, static-methods, private-inheritance

Due to the layout of a third-party library, I have something like the following code:

```
struct Base
{
    static void SomeStaticMethod(){}
};

struct Derived1: private Base {};

struct Derived2: public Derived1 {
    void SomeInstanceMethod(){
        Base::SomeStaticMethod();
    }
};

int main() {
    Derived2 d2;
    d2.SomeInstanceMethod();

    return 0;
}
```

I'm getting compiler error C2247 with MSVC:

> Base::SomeStaticMethod not accessible because Derived1 uses private to inherit from Base.

I know I can't access `Base` members from `Derived2` via inheritance because of the private specifier, but I should still be able to call a static method of `Base` - regardless of any inheritance relationship between `Base` and `Derived2`.
How do I resolve the ambiguity and tell the compiler I'm just making a call to a static method?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Do this:

```
struct Derived2: public Derived1 {
    void SomeInstanceMethod(){
        ::Base::SomeStaticMethod();
//      ^^
//      Notice leading :: for accessing root namespace.
    }
};
```

Comment: This doesn't work (same error C2247).  I'm using MSVC 2013 if that's relevant.

Comment: Are you sure? It *should* work? Did you write the leading `::`?

Comment: Positive.  I copied/pasted your code and cleaned/rebuilt my project.

Comment: It does fix your example when compiled with gcc (4.8 and 6) and with clang(3.7.0).

Comment: Confirmed on my computer - it works with GCC but not MSVC.  I'm marking this as the accepted answer anyway.

Comment: Bill Gates created the MSVC bug, Gill Bates found it :-) this made my day

Comment: @Carlton Does doing `::Base b; b.SomeStaticMethod()` work on MSVC?

Comment: @0x499602D2 Yes, that does work.  It seems that the compiler resolves the class name properly when doing a declaration, but not when calling the static method.  On a side note, omitting the leading `::` produces the same C2247 error for your snippet.

Answer (score 8):

I think michalsrb's answer is better, but for completeness:

```
namespace
{
    void SomeStaticMethodProxy()
    {
        return Base::SomeStaticMethod();
    }
}

struct Derived2: public Derived1 {
    void SomeInstanceMethod(){
        SomeStaticMethodProxy();
    }
};
```

will also work.

Answer (score 8):

Other answers provide way to solve the problem, I'll try to explain what's happening. It's because of *injected-class-name*.

9.2 (N4594)

> [...]The class-name is also inserted into the scope of the class itself; this is known as the injected-class-name.
>   For purposes of access checking, the injected-class-name **is treated as if it were a public member name.**[...]

Note that even if you type `Base::SomeStaticMethod()`, obviously `SomeStaticMethod` is looked up in `Base` scope (It's qualified name), but  name **`Base` itself also has to be looked up somehow**, (In this example as an **unqualified name** (because it does not appear after scope resolution operator))

What happens is that when you search for (unqalified) name `Base` in `Derived2`, first `Derived2` scope is searched, then `Derived1` scope is searched and then `Base` scope is searched and finally *injected-class-name* is found. Then access control takes place (because access control takes place **after** name lookup) and it'll find that name you looked up is `Base`'s member which isn't accessible from `Derived2`.

Comment: Brilliant!  I sort of intuited that something like this must be going on, but this makes it very clear *exactly* what is happening (and explains why putting `::` on the front fixes the problem).

Answer (score 6):

You can do this if you want to call it through the hierarchy:

```
struct Derived1: private Base {
protected:
    using Base::SomeStaticMethod;
};

struct Derived2: public Derived1 {
    void SomeInstanceMethod(){
        Derived1::SomeStaticMethod();
    }
};
```

Otherwise, do as @michalsrb mentioned if you want to call it directly on `Base`.

Answer (score 4):

A couple of possibilities:

1. Don't use the inheritance structure to call the method. Use `::Base::SomeStaticMethod()` to call it. `Base` is accessible in the global namespace.
2. Bring the `private` function into the namespace of `Derived1` by writing `using Base::SomeStaticMethod;`