# No use of base object allowed in private inheritance

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance

I am using *private* inheritance, and I am surprised to see that in the derived class use of any *base* object is not allowed.

```
class A;
class B : private A;
class C : public B;

C::method_1()
{
    A* a; // Temporary "A" object for local computation
}
```

**This has nothing to do with inheritance.** I don't want to access any `this->base method`!

This configuration provide a C2247 error in Visual Studio (" 'A' not accessible, because 'B' use 'private' to inherit from 'A' ").

Comment: Try `::A* a;` instead of `A* a;`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to call a static method from a private base class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39349998/how-to-call-a-static-method-from-a-private-base-class)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Change this:

```
A* a;
```

to this:

```
::A* a;
```

since `C` inherits from `B`, and `B` from `A`, thus you need the scope resolution operator to do the trick.

Instead of starting at the local scope which includes the class parents, `::A` starts looking at the global scope because of the `::`.

From the [Standard](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2015/n4567.pdf):

> **11.1.5 Acess Specifiers**
>
> In a derived class, the lookup of a base class name will find the
>   injected-class-name instead of the name of the base class in the scope
>   in which it was declared. The injected-class-name might be less
>   accessible than the name of the base class in the scope in which it
>   was declared.

Comment: I don't really understand the meanning of the scope operator in that case but it works fine. Thank you !

Comment: @GuillaumeDespine: Instead of starting at the local scope which includes the class parents, `::A` starts looking at the global scope because of the `::`.

Comment: ISO : 11.1 Access Specifiers:  [Note: In a derived class, the lookup of a base class name will ﬁnd the injected-class-name instead of the nameofthebaseclassinthescopeinwhichitwasdeclared. Theinjected-class-namemightbelessaccessible than the name of the base class in the scope in which it was declared. —end note] Has same example

Answer (score 15):

ISO C++: 11.1 Access Specifiers

> 5 [Note: In a derived class, the lookup of a base class name will ﬁnd the injected-class-name instead of the name of the base class in the scope in which it was declared. The injected-class-name might be less accessible than the name of the base class in the scope in which it was declared. —end note]

And the example from the standard:

```
class A { };
class B : private A { };
class C : public B {
    A* p; // error: injected-class-name A is inaccessible
   ::A* q; // OK 
};
```

---

[N3797 Working Draft, Standard for Programming Language C++](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3797.pdf)

Comment: This could get annoying if these classes are all in some nested namespace